# Need help with another binary operation.

Tags: inverse, binary

On the set  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},  I define the operation ⊗ to be like our standard multiplication, except that the result is just the last digit of the product.  For example,  4 ⊗ 7 = 8,  since  4 × 7 = 28,  and 8 is the last digit of 28.  Noticing that 1 is the identity element for ⊗, find the inverse of each element of the set with respect to ⊗ (or if an element doesn’t have an inverse,

Comment: This is really just the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$. Do you know anything about ring?

Comment: I suggest you make a multiplication table. (or since this is group theory a Cayley table.)  You have already pointed out that $1$ is the identity.  For every row of your table, if there is an element equal to the identity, then  that column is the inverse for that row (and vice versa).

Comment: I do not... Am I correct in saying that only 1,3 and 7 have inverses for this problem. 1 being 1 3 being 7 and 7 being 3. 1*1=(1) 3*7=2(1) & 7*3=2(1) as well.

Comment: 9 is the inverse of 9.

Comment: ah, you're right, Doug, forgot about that one.. How would I go about explaining why numbers don't have an inverse? Just by simply stating a*b is not = to x(1)? something in that realm?

Comment: What are the numbers that don't have inverses?  What can you say about their respective lines in the multiplication table.  The even numbers have all even numbers in their lines of the table.  And 0 has nothing but 0's.  And 5 has nothing but 5's and 0's.  I will give you a big hint, it has to do with the fact that there are 10 elements in the set.  Try doing this exercise.  What you have done is called multiplication modulo 10.  Try it in a different base.  i.e. try multiplying the integers less than 7, then taking the remainder when you divide by 7. What do you see there?

Comment: well, 3 and 7 are the only numbers that multiply to a sum ending in a 1